# scroll counter with timer? actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have been trying to do a scroll counter for the past 2 hours and i had no luck. Im new to actionscript 3 flash .. anyways. I am trying to create a text field that is incremented according to time elapsed, any ideas how to do this? Also does flash actionscript 3 update? is there a function that i need to put code under? (im experienced with c# -xna).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what your asking.
If you want the TextField to scroll every time you add a line (thus always having the current line shown) you can just do:

```
myTextField.scrollV = myTextField.maxScrollV;
```

This will force the scroll to the last line of the text box.

not sure about the update question also. You can just use myTextField.text = "asfd"; or myTextField.appendText = "asfd";

If this isn't what you meant please elaborate.

Ok I seen one of your other questions. 
What your probably wanting to do is just have a text field with the game time displayed right? In that case just use.

```
myTimerDisplayTextField.text = playingTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000); // change 1000 to the value you want to update in milliseconds
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
timer.start();
function onTimer():void{
  myTextField.text = 1+myTextField.text;
}
```